# Следование руководству User Interface Guidelines

Tags: android, java

Какие приложения из Android Market вы считаете образцовыми с точки зрения UI и/или следования `Android User Interface Guidelines`? И какие из этих правил, вы считаете, необязательны?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Все что написано в гайдах - обязательно, потому что учитывает лучшие практики по юзабилити, но согласен с тем, что порой можно от них отойти. К примеру, заказчик хочет так, чтобы табы были внизу, как пользователи привыкли в ios и не переспоришь его. Но нужно стараться избавляться от этого, как бы тяжко не было. Пользователи ведь привыкают к тому, что описано, что удобно для них.

По поводу приложений:

1. Winamp
2. стандартные приложения(заметки, Gmail)
3. TuneIn
4. Foursquare
5. MoboPlayer(хотя цвета не ахти)

Все приложения перечислять смысла не вижу.